# Можно ли как-то вывести квадрат из букв S другим способом, используя While?

Tags: java, алгоритм

```
public class Solution
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String S;
    int a = 0;
    while (a<10)
    {

    System.out.println ("SSSSSSSSSS");
        a++;

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да запросто!

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("SSSSSSSSSS\nSSSSSSSSSS\nSSSSSSSSSS\nSSSSSSSSSS\nSSSSSSSSSS\n" +
                             "SSSSSSSSSS\nSSSSSSSSSS\nSSSSSSSSSS\nSSSSSSSSSS\nSSSSSSSSSS\n");
        } while (false);
    }
}
```

Comment: воо, вот это по нашему, по хардкодному=)

Answer (score 5):

Вот вам другой способ с использованием `while`:)

```
public class Solution
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String S;
    int a = 10;
    while ( a-- != 0 )
    {

    System.out.println ("SSSSSSSSSS");

    }

}
}
```

Comment: +1 за сохранение оригинального форматирования

Comment: @VladD Ответ выдан строго в соответствии с вопросом!:) Ничего лишнего!

Answer (score 3):

Ещё вариант от меня

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (a++ == 10) break;

            System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSS");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/3KJ2yT

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.function.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Queue<Consumer<String>> que = new LinkedList<>();
        int q = 0, w = -1;

        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::print);
        q+=w+=2;   que.add(System.out::println);

        while (q --> 0) {
            Consumer<String> c = que.remove();
            c.accept("S");
            que.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Отдельного плюса заслуживает `q --> 0`.

Comment: @VladD: один из самых парадоксальных комментариев, заслуживший вдвое больше плюсов, чем сам вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Хочу за это бедж!

Answer (score 3):

Scala, рекурсия, но while как таковой имеется.

```
  val str = "SSSSSSSSSS"

  def printS(step: Int): Boolean = {
    if (step > 0) {
      println(str)
      printS(step - 1)
    } else false
  }

  while (printS(10)) {}
```

Выдает честный квадрат 10х10 "S".

А вот это грязный хак:

```
object SSSSSSSSSS extends App {

  def SSSSSSSSSS(): Unit = {
    while (true) {
      SSSSSSSSSS()
    }
  }

  SSSSSSSSSS()
}
```

В выводе <s>этой функции</s> этого класса квадрат из букв S есть очень много раз (ниже примерно 1/10 часть результата). Ну и ладно, что не только он :)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
    at SSSSSSSSSS$.SSSSSSSSSS(SSSSSSSSSS.scala:15)
```